# How to check if a custom View has a disabled parent?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a view that does some custom drawing when it's disabled:

```kotlin
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    // Drawing...

    if (!this.isEnabled) {
        // Custom drawing...
    }
}
```

When one of the parent is disabled, it would be logical for it to draw this disabled state as well. However, `isEnabled` is true even when one of the parent views is disabled.

`android:duplicateParentState` looks like it could do it, but I sometimes deeply nest this view and it transfers all states (pressed, etc.).

What is the canonical way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my current solution:

```kotlin
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    // Drawing...

    // Check for both the view and all its parents.
    if (!this.isEnabled || isAnyParentDisabled(parent)) {
        // Custom drawing...
    }
}

private fun isAnyParentDisabled(parent: ViewParent?): Boolean {
    // Recursively check for each parent if it's 
    // a View that has isEnabled set to false.
    val v = parent as? View ?: return false
    return if (v.isEnabled)
        anyParentDisabled(v.parent)
    else
        true
}
```

It works, but it goes through all the parents on each draw.